# How can I bind mediaplayer size to JFXpanel size?

Tags: java, swing, binding, javafx

I have used the code shown previously [How to run a javaFX MediaPlayer in swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562431/how-to-run-a-javafx-mediaplayer-in-swing). 
The code is shown here:

```
public class Test {

 private static void initAndShowGUI() {
     // This method is invoked on Swing thread
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("FX");
     final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
     frame.add(fxPanel);
     frame.setVisible(true);

     Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             initFX(fxPanel);
         }
     });
 }

 private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
     // This method is invoked on JavaFX thread
     Scene scene = createScene();
     fxPanel.setScene(scene);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             initAndShowGUI();
         }
     });
 }
```

}

This works for me and allows a mediaplayer to be shown in a JFXPanel.
However, when I size the JFXPanel so it fits on my screen the player does not size as well.
Can anyone answer how this is done? I think it should involve binding to the JFXpanel but not sure how to implement.
Much appreciate help